# Rails ActiveModel::Dirty in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

When using a rails form to update a boolean value (in my case `shipped`), how can I check to see if this has been set (specifically) from false to true, in order to set a `shipped_at` variable?

At the moment, my update action looks like this:

```
  def update
    @order = @current_shop.orders.find(params[:id])

    if @order.update_attributes(params[:order])
      redirect_to edit_admin_shop_order_path(@current_shop, @order), notice: 'Order was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: "edit"
    end
  end
```

This condition needs to be checked, then `shipped_at` should be assigned (if condition holds) and then obviously, the object should then be saved.

Should I use [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)? How should my controller action look at the end of the day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a responsibility of the model Order itself.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_update :set_shipped_at

  def set_shipped_at
    if self.shipped_was == false && self.shipped == true
      self.shipped_at = Time.now
    end
  end
end
```

Now you don't need to change anything in your controller and if you save the order from another piece of code the shipped_at value will always be set.